# how to copy value from a account field in my case type_of_customer__c of picklist datatype to contact field of same field name?

Tags: apex, trigger

```java
public class contactTriggerHandler {
    
    public void beforeInsert(List<contact> newList)
    {
        set<ID> s= new set<ID>();
        for(contact con: newList)
        {
            if(con.accountId!=null)
            s.add(con.accountID);
        }
         Map<Id,Account> accMap=new Map<Id,Account>([select id,type_of_customer__c from account where id IN :s AND type_of_customer__c!=null]);
        
               
        for(contact c:newList)
        {
            if(c.type_of_customer__c==null)
            {
                if(!accMap.containsKey(c.accountID))
                    c.addError('Value cannot be null');
                else
                    **c.type_of_customer__c=String.valueof(accMap.get(c.accountId));**   
            }
        }
    }
```

error line is *
`c.type_of_customer__c=String.valueof(accMap.get(c.accountId));`

I am getting output as

> Account:{Id=0015j00000kTi8KAAS, Type_of_Customer__c=Premium}

I only want "premium" as output

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the field:

```
c.type_of_customer__c=accMap.get(c.accountId).Type_Of_Customer__c;
```

`String.valueOf` calls `Object.toString` on the object, in this case, an entire `Account` `sObject`.